# Howt to define the structure of $O_Y$-module of sections $S(X,Y)$ of a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I'm trying to solve Exercise II.5.18 from Hartshorne. I quote part (b). Here, $X$ is a vector bundle over $Y$, with projection $f$.

> (b) For any morphism $f : X \to Y$, a section of $f$ over an open set $U
> \subseteq Y$ is a morphism $s: U \to X$ such that $f \circ s = Id_U$.
>   It is clear how to restrict sections to smaller open sets, or how to
>   glue them together, so we see that the presheaf $U \to$ {set of
>   sections of $f$ over $U$} is a sheaf of sets of $Y$, which we denote
>   by $S(X,Y)$. Show that $f:X \to Y$ is a vector bundle of rank $n$,
>   then the sheaf of sections $S(X,Y)$ has a natural structure of
>   $O_Y$-module, which makes it a locally free $O_Y$-module of rank $n$.
>   [*Hint*: it is enough to define the module locally, so we can assume $Y$
>   = Spec $A$ is affine, and $X = \mathbb{A}^n_Y$. Then a section $s : Y \to X$ comes from an $A$-algebra homomorphism $\theta : A[x_1, ..., x_n] \to A$, which in turn determines an ordered $n$-tuple
>   $<\theta(x_1), ..., \theta(x_n)>$ of elements of $A$. Use this
>   correspondence between sections of $s$ and ordered $n$-tuples of
>   elements of $A$ to define the module structure.]

I've just started Algebraic Geometry; this will probably be a basic question, so please bear with me.

Now, I think I "get" the global picture. For example, I understand the sections of a vector bundles on a differentiable manifold determine a module structure over $C^{\infty}$ functions, where the multiplication is pointwise multiplication in the fibers. I just have trouble translating this general picture in algebraic geometry terms. For example, though I understood the correpondence between morphisms of rings and morphism of their spectra, I don't intuitively "see" the correspondence between sections of $Y$ and the $n$-uple mentioned in the exercise, so I don't see how to define the module structure mentioned in the exercise.

Comment: It's kind of tricky because locally $X$ looks like $\mathbb{A}^n_Y$ and we want a module structure on $\mathbb{A}^n_Y$ which should be like adding points and multiplying by scalars. But to do this geometrically, you have to do the opposite of this algebraically and then apply the Spec formalism. If you know about Hopf algebras the idea there is essentially the same one that is used here. Or group schemes, same idea: you want a scheme that is a ``group object" so you need a ring that is a Hopf algebra (but you really want the opposite of a module-scheme).

Comment: You can try to see this by looking at the map, say, from $\mathbb{A}^1\times \mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ (over a field $k$ say) given by the map $k[x]\rightarrow k[x]\otimes_k k[x]$ defined by $x\mapsto x\otimes 1 + 1\otimes x$. Now by the Spec formalism you should look for prime ideals in $k[x]\otimes k[x]$ and then take the preimage to see where they are mapped to. To get a feeling for it, try to show $(x\otimes 1 -n (1\otimes 1), 1\otimes x - m (1\otimes 1))$ has inverse image $(x - n - m)$ (for some elements $n,m \in k$).

Comment: I tried to [write this proof up](https://eoinmackall.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/notes-on-vector-bundles-in-scheme-theory/) a while ago. It doesn't include a proof of the comodule structure on the sheaf of algebras but this is a straightforward construction from the definitions (of the symmetric algebra) once you know what you're looking for. It's painstakingly difficult to prove in full detail though (and the pay off is probably not so worth it once you see the proof). The exact proof you're looking for should have been (6.2) in the notes in the above file.